# Tools to measure statistics of a connection

Tags: gratis, linux, networking, performance-analysis

I set up a SDN using Mininet and Pox, now I need to measure statistics on certain links, such as packet loss. I was suggested to use **Wireshark**. I thought of filtering the arriving packets with tcp.analysis.packet_loss (don't know if it does work for this purpose) but this way I need a client-server tool to generate some TCP traffic to capture, not random TCP, but at least with progressive sequence number (so I can track packet loss). **iperf** is not good for me because I need a tool that doesn't generate "congestion" of a link. Other methods for measuring statics are ok. Can you help me, please?

Comment: I could run an Apache server on one side, and then use wget on the other host to download a file. Wget runs over HTTP, that uses TCP, so it's good for monitoring packet-loss. The only problem is that i need to set a limit on bandwidth usage.

Comment: wget --limit-rate=20k http://....   woudl limit it to 20k/sec

Answer (score 0):

You can almost certainly do this with [python](https://www.python.org/) 2 & [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/).

- Scapy is a packet capture, analysis, manipulation and generation tool.
- Free, gratis & open source
- Cross platform including OS-X, Windows & Linux
- Easily send a set of packets with an incrementing field
- Analysis of the results, *including graphical results*, within the tool
- Scapy can have its own routing table rather than using the system one
- You can save your tests as scripts so as be able to retest later
- Lots of [examples](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#interactive-tutorial) and a [demo](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/demo.html)

Comment: I think scapy does the job, but i was looking for something simple that I don't need to program myself, otherwise I would go for Python and socket programming. I think it's not dead simple to initiate a TCP connection (3-way handshake) and than write a client-server app that waits for ACKs, ecc.

Comment: With scapy it should be almost a one liner

Comment: Can you post an example, please?